# Interactive 3D Model in HTML5

Tags: html, model, 3d, navigation, interactive

does anybody know if its possible to get a 3D model of a building made in 3ds Max for example, onto an HTML5 web-page and make it interactive, for example pans and zooms,maybe even use it for navigation through a site?

If this is not possible in HTML 5 or with such a detailed model does anyone have any recommendations for achieving something similar in say Flash or using a scaled down model?

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL), which uses the HTML5 canvas element.

Answer (score 3):

For WebGL in HTML/ HTML5 you can use
X3D (.x3d): X3DOM => http://x3dom.org | http://github.com/x3dom/x3dom

COLLADA (.dae): Three.js http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js

For Flash there is Away3D:
http://away3d.com/ | http://code.google.com/p/away3d/

Answer (score 0):

The last time I did any work with 3DS was around 1999-2000. Back then it had an 'Export to VRML' feature - if this is still the case you could almost certainly convert (tools are available) VRML to X3D for use with HTML5's Canvas.

You might find @ViennaMike 's answer to [my earlier (related) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497697/is-there-a-high-level-vrml-like-api-for-doing-3d-with-html5) useful for some pointers. He links to some demos and an FAQ.